# What is the definition of "Party retreat" in this context?

Tags: meaning

The headline is:

"At a party retreat in Philadelphia, House Democrats hoped that President Biden would offer a winning strategy heading into a challenging election season."

what is a Party retreat?

Answer (score 2):

A "retreat" is when you go to a relatively secluded place.

For instance:

- a writer can go on a retreat to write their book undisturbed;
- any person can go on a retreat to take time for themselves, for introspection and meditation;
- the members of a political party can go on a retreat together to discuss party-related matters.

Definition of "retreat" from WordReference dictionary:

> a withdrawal for quiet thinking, such as for meditation:
>
> *"The priests go on a retreat once a year."*
>
> *"They cannot be reached this week; they are on retreat."*